# script import csv to terminal shell (zoc)

Tags: shell, csv, terminal

first of all its a really awesome and informative forum. 
The question to you guys is i need a script to import from an excel, cvs, or text (with ip addreses)
into the terminal tool zoc or putty:

The first script output line is:

CALL ZocTimeout 60
CALL ZocWaitForSeq "on"

CALL ZocConnect "xxxxxxxxx@85.26.0.12:22"

CALL ZocWait "SW-201#"
CALL ZocSend "term len 0 ^M sh run ^M sh interf status ^M sh vers ^M sh mac address-table ^M sh cdp neigh^M exit ^M"

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Bash is Turing complete, so anything is possible.
But a much more appropriate tool would take advantage of an "Expect" library, e.g. https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

You will also be able to conveniently parse your CSV with https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: What about (REXX Script language) for ZOC?

Can somebody me explain to invert (outline code) an excel or txt into zoc?

Because my bash skills are nood good as all.